# Default image for paperclip, if image deleted from disk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Suppose, I add `Paperclip` attachment to my model instance (for example `@company.logo`), and then remove file from disk. Then `@company.logo.url` still return path to attachment (for example `/system/companies/:id/original/test_image.jpg`). How I can return default url, if file is not exists on disk? `:default_url` option doesn't work in this case. My Paperclip version: 3.5.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the file is missing and if so delete it with something like this:

```
file_to_test = 'public/system/companies/:id/original/test_image.jpg'

if !File.exist?(file_to_test)

  company.logo.destroy
  company.save

end
```

Comment: The question is how to return the default_url if the file no longer exists on the disk.  This does not answer the question.